# cmake generate assembly file then compile it into executable

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, cmake

I'm using cmake, and let's say I have a .cpp file.
Is it possible in cmake to compile this cpp file into assembly code first, then do some other operation and after that create executable from the generated assembly?

Update:
So basically I want to compile Hello.cpp to Hello.s (later modify it, and then create the object file). However I can't generate the asm file with that code (It just creates a Hello.a static library):

```
add_library(Tutorial Hello.cpp)
set_target_properties(Tutorial PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-S") 
install (TARGETS Tutorial DESTINATION bin)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call shell command after asm file generation in cmake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41987775/call-shell-command-after-asm-file-generation-in-cmake)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CMake does always generate "assembly file rules" for you. So let's say you have:

```
file(WRITE main.cpp "int main() { return 0; }")
add_executable(MyMain main.cpp)
```

You can call `make` for targets `main.s` or `main.cpp.s` like:

```
> make main.cpp.s
Compiling CXX source to assembly CMakeFiles/MyMain.dir/main.cpp.s
```

But if you want to automate everything, see my answer at your other question:

- [Call shell command after asm file generation in cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41987775/call-shell-command-after-asm-file-generation-in-cmake/41989789#41989789)

Answer (score -1):

You can tell GCC to only generate assembly with the `-S` option.

You can also tell GCC to keep intermediate files with `-save-temps`.

Comment: I think the `-save-temps` won't be ok for me, because I want to modify the asm file before linking.

Comment: Then use `-S`, and pass it back to gcc. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? There is probably a way to do what you want directly in your source code.

Comment: I'm trying to implement this in cmake.  It is working in the terminal. I create the asm file with `-S`, I can modify the asm file and I can compile it as well. My problem is that I can't implement this in cmake.