# Call shell command after asm file generation in cmake

Tags: android, assembly, makefile, cmake

In android mk files it is possible to call a shell command right after generating assembly files with LOCAL_FILTER_ASM.

I was wondering is there any workaround to have something similar in cmake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I admit I had lookup [what `LOCAL_FILTER_ASM` does](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk.html).

So the following is my piece of code (same functionality just in CMake):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(LocalFilterASM C ASM)

set(LOCAL_FILTER_ASM "cp")

string(
    REPLACE 
        "<ASSEMBLY_SOURCE>" "<OBJECT>.S.original" 
        MY_CREATE_ASSEMBLY "${CMAKE_C_CREATE_ASSEMBLY_SOURCE}"
)
string(
   REPLACE 
        "<SOURCE>" "<OBJECT>.S" 
         MY_COMPILE_OBJECT "${CMAKE_ASM_COMPILE_OBJECT}"
)

set(
    CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT 
        "${MY_CREATE_ASSEMBLY}"
        "${LOCAL_FILTER_ASM} <OBJECT>.S.original <OBJECT>.S"
        "${MY_COMPILE_OBJECT}"
) 

file(WRITE main.c "int main(void) { return 0; }")
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.c)
```

This just takes some of the existing CMake compiler rules and combines it into a new multi-line rule for [`CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILE_OBJECT.html). Please note that this will only work with CMake's makefile generators.

Comment: Great answer! I didn't know about the CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT.

Comment: I executed on a bigger project, and seems it generates assembly files with the "o.s" and "o.S.original" extension, because I believe the <OBJECT> stands for the object files. 
It works well, however it is a bit confusing to see these "o.s" extensions.

Comment: @loz That's the problem with CMake's [expansion rules](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables#Expansion_Rules). They don't have something for "source name only", so I can't reference/create something custom in the binary output directory. As a fallback I extended the object's output path.

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to say since you haven't provided any example of what you currently have.

However, you can use the [add_custom_command()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html) function to add before and after scripts to any target (see the bottom of the page in the "Build Events" section for the syntax you want).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to use the  add_custom_command(), but it has only three build event (prebuild,prelink,postbuild). In my case I would need a build event which is triggered right after the asm file generation.

Comment: Well, like said, since you don't show your current cmake rules there's not much we can say about it.  I (at least) am not familiar with Android makefiles or LOCAL_FILTER_ASM.  Are you trying to insert some operation into the middle of the compilation of every source file, that will operate on the generated assembly and then use the results of that operation to generate the object file?