# Android CMakeLists.txt - How to output assembly listing

Tags: android, android-ndk, cmake, clang

I have the following line in my **CMakeLists.txt** file:

```
set_target_properties(native-lib PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-save-temps")
```

This tells the compiler to preserve the assembly in a ***.s** file.

I need to know how to make this include the **assembly listing** though.

i.e. Have the C source beside the assembly in the *.s file.

I believe this is normally done with the -l flag but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41989789/637669

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-save-temps` is not about this at all. You need `-S` flag to generate assembly listings. Unfortunately, you cannot <s>eat the cake and have it</s> create assembly and object files in same run. With **cmake**, you can add this file either via the script:

```
set_target_properties(native-lib PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-S")
```

or through **build.gradle**:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    externalNativeBuild { 
      cmake {
        cFlags "-S"
```

In either case, your build will fail, but you can collect the assembly listings from **.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi/CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp**. You may choose to manually rename these files from `*.o` to `*.s`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this and the build is successful. There is nothing in the mentioned folder afterwards and after removing -save-temps there is no .s file anymore. I also tried it with both -S and -save-temps but no luck.

Comment: Maybe you have cpp files, then you need `cppFlags`.

Comment: If you add `arguments '-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON'` you will see the actual compile commands in your gradle console.

Comment: Okay thanks I got the .o file to show up in the folder you mentioned by using cppFlags "-S" in the build.gradle file and ignoring the cmake file. Unfortunately this is not the assembly listing. It's assembly yes but there is no mixed C with it,

Comment: This [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24603910/192373) to be not supported by clang. You can switch to GCC, but it is another compiler, and it is being discouraged in NDK.

Comment: It's almost worth it for this... I tried the suggested workaround on the page you linked but it doesn't work either. This is really disappointing. Thanks for the help mate.